# File Server Design Approaches

Tags: web

I have been working on designing a file server that could take the load off from the primary website, and serve images/files over the web to the client.

Primary goals of the file server:
- Take off load from primary server hosting the site
- Reuse the existing web server code base and avoid duplication of code/logic for better maintainability
- Being scalable for increasing downloads
- Hide real download url path from user

By keeping above in mind, i could come up with two approaches. Sequence diagram representation of the two approaches for ease of understanding [apologies for the skewed use of sequence diagram]. Neither of the approaches would satisfy all my goals.

Which of these approaches would you recommend considering my goals?
Is there a better third approach?

Some of the differences, i could think of:
- Approach #1 would result in duplicating BL code causing maintainability issues
- Approach #2 would reuse code and centralize BL reducing maintainability issues
- Approach #1 would reduce network calls while #2 increases them

The concept of file servers, scalability of downloads, bandwidth distribution have all been there for a while now. Please share your thoughts!

[image]

UPDATED:
Approach #1 looks very attractive as it takes the load off the primary server completely. The only issue to address in #1 is the code duplication and maintainability issues. This could be overcome by having just one project for BL/DAC comprising the functionality required by both web service and file server. And, reference the assembly/library in both web service and file server projects. Now, there is only one BL/DAC code to maintain and also avoids the network calls in approach #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By serving images/files to the client, I assume you mean static files css, js etc.

Most of the time, a simple solution is the best solution.  Just host them on a different server under a different subdomin, i.e. http://content.mydomain.com/img/xyz.jpg.  You could host them at a data centre on dedicated server giving your perforamace (close to the backbone), you could load balance the url and by have 2+ servers at 2+ different data centers, giving you resilliance and scalability.

You maintence task is then having todo find a replace when promoting your site to live to replace dev/uat content paths with the live content path (tho you'd only need todo this in css files as you could store the paths for content used within aspx files for as config data).

Comment: @Jaimal: By files, i mean documents stored on the webserver/db that were uploaded by the user. Goal is to make it scalable later to host on a data center.

Comment: @Pencilslate: Hmm, on upload, rewrite the file name with a guid making a hard to read url and 99.99% unique url, write the file to a separate server. Store the guidas your indexed column in an db along with other meta data (file name size, type date of upload etc etc).  Then when the file is requested, grab the file using the guid.  You can quickly rewrite the filename to its original when sending down the repsonse stream.

You've thus already created your unique filename and therefore unique d/l url and don;t have to create one at the time of request.